# VK API и PHP: токен сбрасывается после выполнения первой команды

Tags: вконтакте, php, vkontakte-api

Пишу небольшой PHP-скрипт, постит месседж в группу/обсуждения. Проблема такая: после авторизации через oauth дает токен с редиректом на http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html, ну я его руками оттуда вытаскиваю (можно ли как-то не руками оттуда его вытащить?). Вытащил, в параметрах указано `scope=offline`, но при этом токен сбрасывается после выполнения первой команды, и второй раз им воспользоватся уже нельзя. Что я делаю не так?

```
 $params = array(
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri'  => 'http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,notifications,stats,ads,offline'
    );
http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?'. urldecode(http_build_query($params))
```

Comment: Что за vk.com/blank.html? В redirect_uri нужно указывать свой URL. И там уже `code` достаётся как `$_GET['code']`. И после получения `access_token` по этому коду проверьте параметр `expires_in`.

Comment: redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html 
Это обязательное условие для работы с методами, в описании которых указано, что они доступны только для Desktop-приложений.

Comment: Однако в документации ("Авторизация клиентских приложений") написано несколько другое.

Comment: Это цитата именно оттуда.

Comment: А почитать дальше и попытаться понять смысл reditect_uri?

Comment: Там ничего особо интересного нет, если вы могли бы подсказать, то подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Стоп, меня смутили слова "php скрипт". Это всё-таки сайт или standalone=-приложение? В любом случае надо посмотреть что приходит в `expires_in`.

Comment: Мне нужно запостить в обсуждение коммент, там только с десткоп приложения, якобы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот хорошая ссылка на вечный токен

{ПРАВА} - пишешь свои права

{APPID} - там стандалон приложение

вот мое, если нужно - 4407314

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={APPID}&https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope={ПРАВА},offline&display=popup&response_type=token&v=5.21

Вот полная готовая ссылка

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4407314&https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,notifications,stats,ads,offline&display=popup&response_type=token&v=5.21